# How to correctly calculate an improper integral with Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 13.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0 or later.**

---

I try in version 13 on Windows 10

```
j = Integrate[Exp[a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity,
Infinity}, Assumptions -> {a, b, c} ∈ Reals]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[(2 π)/(Sqrt[-4 a + b^2/c] Sqrt[-c]),  4 a c^2 < b^2 c]`

The above result is not correct, as

```
j /. {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 1}
```

> `-((2 I π)/Sqrt[5])`

and

```
Integrate[Exp[a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2] /. {a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 1}, {x,-Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> Integrate::idiv:Integral of E^(x^2+3 x y+y^2) does not converge on {-∞,∞}.

demonstrate.

Is it possible to correctly calculate that integral with Mathematica? I tried to use the definition. Because the integrand is positive, it is enough to calculate

```
Integrate[Exp[a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2], {x, -d, d}, {y, -d, d}, 
 Assumptions -> {a, b, c} ∈ Reals && d > 0]
```

exhausting the plane over the squares and then to find the limit as `d->Infinity`. However, the latest integral almost crashes my comp.

Comment: `Integrate[Exp[a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2], {x, -d, d}, {y, -d, d}, 
 Assumptions -> {a, b, c} \[Element] Reals && d > 0, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]` returns  a one-dimensional integral.

Comment: The same issue with `Integrate[Exp[a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2], {x, -d, d}, {y, -d, d}, 
 Assumptions -> {a, b, c} > 0 && d > 0]`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with help of Mathematica as follows.
Let us exhaust the plane by disks centered at the origin. Switching to the polar coordinates, one obtains

```
Integrate[r*Exp[a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2] /. {x -> r*Cos[ϕ],y -> r*Sin[ϕ]}, {r, 0, R}]
```

> `(-1 + E^(R^2 (a Cos[ϕ]^2 + b Cos[ϕ] Sin[ϕ] +  c Sin[ϕ]^2)))/(a + c + (a - c) Cos[2 ϕ] +  b Sin[2 ϕ])`

It is clear the finite limit of the function defined by the above expression as `R->Infinity` exists only if `ForAll[ϕ, ϕ > -Pi && ϕ <= Pi,  a Cos[ϕ]^2 + b Cos[ϕ] Sin[ϕ] + c Sin[ϕ]^2 < 0]` is valid as the result of

```
Integrate[r*Exp[a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2] /. {x -> r*Cos[ϕ], y -> r*Sin[ϕ]},
{r, 0,Infinity},Assumptions -> {a, b, c} ∈ Reals && ϕ > -Pi && ϕ <= Pi]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[-(1/( 2 (a Cos[ϕ]^2 + b Cos[ϕ] Sin[ϕ] + c Sin[ϕ]^2))), a Cos[ϕ]^2 + b Cos[ϕ] Sin[ϕ] + c Sin[ϕ]^2 < 0]`

demonstrates.

Unfortunately, Mathematica fails with

```
Resolve[ForAll[ϕ, ϕ > -Pi && ϕ <= Pi, 
a Cos[ϕ]^2 + b Cos[ϕ] Sin[ϕ] + c Sin[ϕ]^2 <  0], Reals]
```

, returning the input. However, Mathematica is able to derive the condition in such a way

```
Resolve[ForAll[y, y >= -1 && y <= 1,a y^2 + b *y*Sqrt[1 - y^2] + c (1 - y^2) < 0], Reals]
```

> `c < 0 && a < b^2/(4 c)`

Now

```
Integrate[(-1)/(a + c + (a - c) Cos[2 ϕ] + b Sin[2 ϕ]), {ϕ, -Pi, Pi}, 
Assumptions -> c < 0 && a < b^2/(4 c) && a < 0 && b ∈ Reals]
```

results in

> `ConditionalExpression[ -Piecewise[{{0, (Sqrt[Abs[-(a/(a - I*b - c)) - c/(a - I*b - c) - Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c]/(a - I*b - c)]] < 1 &&  Sqrt[Abs[-(a/(a - I*b - c)) - c/(a - I*b - c) + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c]/(a - I*b - c)]] < 1) ||  (Sqrt[Abs[-(a/(a - I*b - c)) - c/(a - I*b - c) - Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c]/(a - I*b - c)]] >= 1 &&  Sqrt[Abs[-(a/(a - I*b - c)) - c/(a - I*b - c) + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c]/(a - I*b - c)]] >= 1)},  {(2*Pi)/Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c], Sqrt[Abs[-(a/(a - I*b - c)) - c/(a - I*b - c) + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c]/(a - I*b - c)]] <  1}}, (-2*Pi)/Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c]],  !(Sqrt[Abs[-(a/(a - I*b - c)) - c/(a - I*b - c) - Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c]/(a - I*b - c)]] >= 1 &&  Sqrt[Abs[-(a/(a - I*b - c)) - c/(a - I*b - c) - Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c]/(a - I*b - c)]] <= 1) &&  !(Sqrt[Abs[-(a/(a - I*b - c)) - c/(a - I*b - c) + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c]/(a - I*b - c)]] >= 1 &&  Sqrt[Abs[-(a/(a - I*b - c)) - c/(a - I*b - c) + Sqrt[-b^2 + 4*a*c]/(a - I*b - c)]] <= 1)]`

, thinking a few hours. In fact, this is $$\frac{2 \pi }{\sqrt{4 a c-b^2}} $$ as `Simplify` under the conditions `c < 0 && a < b^2/(4 c) && a < 0 && b ∈ Reals]` shows.